# For iteration on scalatra input

Tags: scala, scalatra

I am trying to read input in scalatra webapp using for iteration in below manner

```
for (
         input1<- params.getOrElse("input1", "");
         input2 <- params.getOrElse("input2", "");
         search <- params.getOrElse("search", false)
    ) {
       //Perform action
    }
```

It is throwing error value foreach is not a member of Object.

In case if user doesn't provide any input, it should default empty string and call the action instead of breaking out of loop. For that reason i am using getOrElse. But i haven't succeeded.

Any help?

Comment: What is the type of `params`? I guess it's a `Map[String, Something]`, so you should replace `input1 <- params.getOrElse(...)` with `val input1 = params.getOrElse(...)` (same for `input2` and `search`) and remove `for`, but you'll get values of type `Any` since you are using different types in `getOrElse` (`String` and `Boolean`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for-comprehensions to work with `Option` but you can't use it for objects that don't have at least one defined `foreach`, `map` or `flatMap`. In your case, if `params` is returning options then...

```
for(
  input1 <- params get "input1"
  input2 <- params get "input2"
 ){
   //do stuff
 }
```

Wherein this will not run if both `input` and `input2` are not `None`.

If you don't want to short circuit the control logic and you want there to be sane defaults for `Option` returns, then a better way is just to do

```
 myFunction(params getOrElse ("input1", "default1"), params getOrElse ("input2", 42))
```

where you're explicitly providing the defaults and passing them into a function call.

Comment: Don't you think that `val input1 = params.getOrElse("input1", "")` is what OP wants.

Comment: @senia No. He's doing a side-effecting operation with the results. There's no need to store the value once passed into the function.